# Issue in typescript with generics: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm learning some typescript but I'm not entirely sure what the problem in my code is.

I'm trying to implement an event system to make my domain observable (similar to what C# has with events) in a generic way and it compiles without a hitch. It even shows the correct type inference in intellisense (for sender?) when I register a handler.

But when I try to run it I keep getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined " in the __extends helper function.

This is my code:

```
module Pathing.Domain {

export interface IEventArgs {

}

export interface EventHandler<S,T extends IEventArgs> {
    (sender?: S, e?: T): void
}

export class StdEvent<S> extends EventDelegate<S, IEventArgs> {

}

export class EventDelegate<S, T> {
    private handlers: EventHandler<S,T>[] = [];

    public add(handler: EventHandler<S, T>): void {
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }

    public remove(handler: EventHandler<S, T>): void {
        this.handlers = this.handlers.filter(h => h != handler);
    }

    public raise(...args: any[]): void {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++)
            this.handlers[i].call(this, args);
    }
}


}
```

I can also simulate it on the playground: [http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20module%20Pathing.Domain%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IEventArgs%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20EventHandler%3CS%2CT%20extends%20IEventArgs%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(sender%3F%3A%20S%2C%20e%3F%3A%20T)%3A%20void%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20StdEvent%3CS%3E%20extends%20EventDelegate%3CS%2C%20IEventArgs%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20EventDelegate%3CS%2C%20T%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20handlers%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2CT%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20add(handler%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2C%20T%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers.push(handler)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20remove(handler%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2C%20T%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers%20%3D%20this.handlers.filter(h%20%3D%3E%20h%20!%3D%20handler)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20raise(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20this.handlers.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers%5Bi%5D.call(this%2C%20args)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20module%20Pathing.Domain%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20IEventArgs%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20EventHandler%3CS%2CT%20extends%20IEventArgs%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28sender%3F%3A%20S%2C%20e%3F%3A%20T%29%3A%20void%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20StdEvent%3CS%3E%20extends%20EventDelegate%3CS%2C%20IEventArgs%3E%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20EventDelegate%3CS%2C%20T%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20handlers%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2CT%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20add%28handler%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2C%20T%3E%29%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers.push%28handler%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20remove%28handler%3A%20EventHandler%3CS%2C%20T%3E%29%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers%20%3D%20this.handlers.filter%28h%20%3D%3E%20h%20!%3D%20handler%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20raise%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20this.handlers.length%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.handlers%5Bi%5D.call%28this%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A)

I've got the same problem in Internet explorer (which I used for debugging in vs2013) and chrome.

Has anyone got a clue what might be wrong?

--

Edit: It looks like the culprit is `export class StdEvent<S> extends EventDelegate<S, IEventArgs> {`

Can anyone shed some light as why this results in a runtime error yet the compiler happily agrees with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base class `EventDelegate` needs to be defined before the derived class `StdEvent`

```
export class EventDelegate {

}

export class StdEvent extends EventDelegate {
}
```

It's conceivable that in a future version the TypeScript compiler would take care of this for you, but until then you are responsible for ordering the definitions correctly.

Comment: I would also use the term "defined" (not declared) but doesn't matter.

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I missed something so obvious, thanks a lot!

Comment: @basarat yes, defined (not declared).